# Write a Python script to generate a random DataFrame based on specific inputs

Tags: python, pandas

I found myself many times in the past trying to generate fake DataFrames in `pandas`. I decided just for fun, to write a script that I can specify some inputs and generate that DataFrame for me. Here you can find the code:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from faker import Faker

def generate_dummy_dataframe(int_cols, float_cols, bool_cols, string_cols, datetime_cols, rows):
  """
  Generates a dummy dataframe with the specified number of columns and rows for each data type.

  Parameters
  ----------
  int_cols : int
      The number of integer columns to create.
  float_cols : int
      The number of float columns to create.
  bool_cols : int
      The number of boolean columns to create.
  string_cols : int
      The number of string columns to create.
  datetime_cols : int
      The number of datetime columns to create.
  rows : int
      The number of rows to create.

  Returns
  -------
  df : pandas.DataFrame
      A dataframe with the specified number of columns and rows for each data type, filled with sample data.
      
  Raises
  ------
  ValueError
      If any of the inputs is not an integer greater than 0.
  """
  # Check that input is valid
  if not all(isinstance(i, int) and i > 0 for i in [int_cols, float_cols, bool_cols, string_cols, datetime_cols, rows]):
    raise ValueError("All inputs must be integers greater than 0.")

  # Create empty dataframe
  df = pd.DataFrame()

  # Create instance of Faker
  fake = Faker()

  # Add integer columns
  for i in range(int_cols):
    df['int_col_{}'.format(i)] = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(rows)]
  
  # Add float columns
  for i in range(float_cols):
    df['float_col_{}'.format(i)] = [random.uniform(0, 100) for _ in range(rows)]
  
  # Add boolean columns
  for i in range(bool_cols):
    df['bool_col_{}'.format(i)] = [random.choice([1, 0]) for _ in range(rows)]
  
  # Add string columns
  for i in range(string_cols):
    df['string_col_{}'.format(i)] = [fake.word() for _ in range(rows)]
  
  # Add datetime columns
  for i in range(datetime_cols):
    df['datetime_col_{}'.format(i)] = [fake.date_time() for _ in range(rows)]
  
  return df
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
 generate_dummy_dataframe(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10)
```

And generate the output as this:

```
   int_col_0  int_col_1  float_col_0  float_col_1  bool_col_0  bool_col_1  \
0         26         13    51.154902    74.562551           1           1   
1         84          6    94.790006    22.036552           1           1   
2         90         23    53.832429    29.791543           0           0   
3         64         94     4.101628    18.442224           0           0   
4         85         21    17.637843    51.384612           1           0   
5         16         62    43.132250    99.989500           0           0   
6          7         61    29.019135    90.812649           0           0   
7          7         44    32.686915    80.988226           0           1   
8         75         41    89.628566     5.697429           0           0   
9         95         32    46.610747    19.376951           0           1   

  string_col_0 string_col_1      datetime_col_0      datetime_col_1  
0         fish      network 2012-12-30 11:15:50 2002-09-14 08:39:36  
1     industry         rich 2004-09-21 13:26:07 1972-01-18 22:55:46  
2        coach         feel 2018-12-08 03:25:36 1998-06-19 18:18:27  
3        image        price 2017-07-16 19:37:53 2014-02-17 03:10:18  
4     anything        place 2015-01-19 20:45:41 2003-06-08 06:37:41  
5      century     possible 2004-06-02 02:35:25 1992-03-29 06:26:31  
6        other       expert 1985-04-14 16:27:21 2008-09-30 11:43:44  
7        sound     approach 1975-07-05 03:48:37 1978-03-20 00:08:46  
8  information         very 1989-10-15 15:52:22 2001-10-17 14:38:37  
9           us         more 1990-09-26 09:19:54 1975-01-11 12:07:19
```

**Areas that I could improve this:**

*Performance*

It's clear that the more rows I ask for, it will take even more time.

```
import time

def test_execution_time(rows):
  start = time.time()
  df = generate_dummy_dataframe(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, rows)
  end = time.time()
  print("Number of rows: {}".format(rows))
  print("Execution time: {} seconds".format(end - start))

# Test execution time for different number of rows
test_execution_time(100)
test_execution_time(1000)
test_execution_time(10000)
test_execution_time(100000)
test_execution_time(1000000)

Number of rows: 100
Execution time: 0.05393719673156738 seconds
Number of rows: 1000
Execution time: 0.12861156463623047 seconds
Number of rows: 10000
Execution time: 1.0118906497955322 seconds
Number of rows: 100000
Execution time: 9.85063910484314 seconds
Number of rows: 1000000
Execution time: 98.54737830162048 seconds
```

*Less libraries*

Get rid of faker. The string columns doesn't have to be valid words. Just a dummy short text. Similar for datetime. I guess I can do that without faker.

*Readability*

Not sure here. Is there anything that can be done to make it more Pythonic and better formatted?

Comment: why can't a column be 0?

Comment: Good point. I missed that when I was thinking about the rows input. I will change it so the columns can be 0 but rows >0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re. performance: you're (forgive me) going about it all wrong. Performant code requires that you

- allocate memory contiguously whenever possible
- use the vectorisation capabilities of your libraries, in this case Numpy, rather than loops

That requires a rewrite, which I will partially demonstrate. Otherwise:

Use PEP484 typehints and pull that information away from the docstring.

The docstring is repetitive. If the description and `Returns` say the same thing, scrap the description and keep the `Returns`.

Your validation hides the specific problem. Loop through and include the name of the problematic column in your error message.

I demonstrate a method to generate datetimes without Faker. Strings are also possible but I leave this as an exercise to the reader.

The parameters are both too verbose and not generic enough. You can reframe this as a single dictionary (or, if you want, kwargs) of dtypes to column counts. This will be called like

```
df = generate_dummy_df(
    cols={
        np.uint8: 4,
        np.bool_: 1,
        np.float64: 2,
        'datetime64[s]': 1,
        'datetime64[ms]': 1,
        'datetime64[ns]': 1,
    },
    rows=20,
)
```

### Suggested

On my nothing-special computer, this generates 10,000,000 rows in 1.3 seconds. Mind you it's not apples-to-apples because I don't include strings.

```
from timeit import timeit
from typing import Optional, Union

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng


def generate_dummy_df(cols: dict[Union[str, np.dtype], int], rows: int, seed: Optional[int] = None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    cols
        The number of columns to create for each given datatype.
    rows
        The number of rows to create.
    seed
        Provided to the random generator.

    Returns
    -------
    df
        A dummy dataframe filled with random data.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        If any of the inputs is not an integer greater than 0.
    """

    for dtype, n in cols.items():
        if not isinstance(n, int) or n < 1:
            raise ValueError(f"{dtype} must have a positive column count")

    if not isinstance(rows, int) or rows < 1:
        raise ValueError(f'{rows} is not a valid row count')

    rand = default_rng(seed)

    def make_cols():
        y20_in_ns = 20 * 365.2425 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1e9
        start = np.datetime64('2000-01-01', 'ns')
        end = start + np.timedelta64(int(y20_in_ns), 'ns')

        for dtype, n in cols.items():
            shape = n, rows
            mode = dict(size=shape, dtype=dtype)

            if np.issubdtype(dtype, np.integer):
                array = rand.integers(**mode, low=0, high=100)
            elif np.issubdtype(dtype, np.floating):
                # uniform() does not support dtype. Also, this will only work with float32 or float64.
                # For something more exotic, you need a separate branch.
                array = rand.random(**mode)*100.
            elif np.issubdtype(dtype, np.bool_):
                array = rand.integers(**mode, low=0, high=1, endpoint=True)
            elif np.issubdtype(dtype, np.datetime64):
                array = rand.integers(
                    size=shape, dtype=np.int64, low=start, high=end
                ).astype('datetime64[ns]').astype(dtype)
            else:
                raise ValueError(f'Type {dtype.__name__} is not supported')

            for i, col in enumerate(array):
                if isinstance(dtype, str):
                    type_name = dtype
                else:
                    type_name = dtype.__name__
                yield f'{type_name}_col_{i}', col

    return pd.DataFrame(dict(make_cols()))


def run_test():
    return generate_dummy_df(
        cols={
            np.int64: 5,
            np.float64: 5,
            np.bool_: 5,
            'datetime64[ns]': 5,
        },
        rows=10_000_000,
    )

t = timeit(run_test, number=1)
print(t)
```

Comment: Wow, that's a totally new world to me. I need to study the code and understand what you did. But performance wised, it is day and night :)